# How to design a base class that needs to join a thread in its destructor, which operates on the same class instance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, polymorphism, race-condition, stdthread

I just got a juicy race condition. Consider the following classes:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A
{
    std::thread th;
    std::atomic_bool stop = false;

  public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A &) = delete;
    A &operator=(const A &) = delete;

    ~A()
    {
        stop.store(true);
        th.join();
    }

    virtual void Step() = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        th = std::thread([this]
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (stop.load())
                    return;

                // Just to help reproduce the race condition.
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));

                Step();
            }
        });
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    void Step() override
    {
        std::cout << "Step!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    b.Start();

    // Just to help reproduce the race condition.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(110));
}
```

This crashes due to a pure virtual function call (if we ignore the data race UB).

Right before we enter the body of `~A()`, before we can stop the thread, the vtable pointer is changed to point to `A`'s vtable, so the next call of `Step()` crashes, now being a pure virtual call.

This can be fixed by stopping the thread in `~B()`, but that means every derived class must remember to do it, or bad things will happen.

I wish I could design `A` to take care of this by itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Nope, this cannot be done. You're running into core fundamental principles of how C++ objects work. Been there, done that. Either the class hierarchy needs to be redesigned, or every derived class must be responsieble for invoking a base class's method (that stops the execution thread) in its destructor (and the base class method needs to be smart about being invoked multiple times).

Comment: Do you need inheritance? i.e move `virtual void Step()` from `A` to an interface `IJob` and take a `std::unique<IJob>`. Alternatively, use CRTP...

Comment: @Jarod42 `IJob` sounds like a good idea. I considered CRTP, but I think it's going to suffer the same problem?

Comment: Indeed, CRTP shouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: How about stub the callback/function instead of captureing `this` in `Start()`? Since `Step()` works in destructor, it should be stateless?

Comment: If you add to your program `void A::Step() {}`, then there will not be crash due to pure virtual function call.

Comment: @Fedor Yep, but there would still a data race UB on the vtable pointer,.

Comment: @LouisGo What do you mean by a stub? Regarding making `Step()` stateless, I'd prefer derived classes to not have to think about it, and just be able to put anything in there.

Comment: If `B::Step()` accesses fields of `B` then the thread must be stopped before running `~B()`. So it shall be a responsibility of child class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry stub is confusing. I meant `A::Step()` should be something like `void Step(){ m_callback() }`. Where `m_callback` is a function pointer or `std::function`. All the derived class should set the callback before executes the thread or derived destructor executes. Then the callback itself should only capture variables that lifetime is longer than derived class. Though it could only be taken care by the writer of derived class...

Comment: In another way, I suggest the design to include an interface like `ITeardown` to take care of this case before destructor. like `void tearDown(){ stop.store(true); th.join();}` That makes the design simpler without dealing with object lifetimes..